# How much value do groupsets gain/loose per year?

Tags: shopping

What is the difference in value of a last-year component, and the equivalent one from this year? For example an SLX rear derailleur, an X0 crankset, a Fox Float fork.

How substantial is technology trickle-down. If a brand new bike from last year costs x, and the frame is unchanged, what could be expected the worth of the components to be, compared to the 2014 model? For example 5% less?

Comment: Looking at the end-of-season sales, I'd suspect worse than 20% for the whole bike, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There is precious little increase in value from one year's model to the next.  A new model number/name provides bragging rights and allows the old stock to be sold at discount without "devaluing" the new stuff.

Comment: 2 downvotes? Why?

Comment: It is an important question for anyone comparing new bike to last year's  discounted model, or for anyone considering a second-hand bike: 1990-s Deore is not the same as today's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, it depends on how much has actually changed. Usually the lower quality groups (Shimana Alivio/Deore, SRAM X5/X7) don't change too much because they are very similar to the OEM parts. However, the more expensive groupsets incorporate the trickle down method you mention. Things like clutch derailleurs are becoming available in the middle price ranges versus the top tier. Adding something like that will greatly decrease the previous year's model, while increasing the new one's.

Most of the time though, it's like a car. As soon as you drive it off the lot, the value drops. Even if it's brand new, as soon as the next year rolls around it's lost value. Marketing and hype are what sell product and new product is always pushed first.

Comment: So ... it depends what has happened. Apparently 2014's Alivio is going to be [a lot different](http://www.mtb-bg.com/index.php/products/news/2674-products-news-2014-shimano-alivio-2014-2015): shadow rear derailleur, hydraulic brakes, 29-er oriented chainrings.