# What bike is better 2010 Trek FX 7.5 or 2015 Trek FX 7.2?

Tags: used-bike

My budget allows for maxing out at $500. The LBS sells the new 2015 Trek FX 7.2 for $450. I also found an excellent condition 2010 Trek FX 7.5 for roughly the same price. Assuming the used bike is in excellent condition with less than 300 miles of use, should I be worried about the 5 year model difference of the two bikes?

I'm upgrading from a 2008 Trek Navigator 3.0 that is too cumbersome for longer rides. I ride trails with the kids, charity rides, and occasional commuting.

These are the specs as specified by Trek's website. I realize the 2010 FX 7.5 has better specs but should I be worried about their age? Or with these bike components is usage more important than age?

**2010 FX 7.5**

Frame: FX Alpha Black Aluminum
Fork: Bontrager Nebula, carbon w/Clix dropouts
Wheels: Bontrager SSR w/Clix
Tyres: Bontrager Race Lite Hard-Case, 700x32c
Shifters: Shimano Deore trigger, 9 speed
Front derailleur: Shimano Deore
Rear derailleur: Shimano Deore LX
Crank: Shimano M443 Octalink 48/36/26
Cassette: SRAM PG950 11-26, 9 speed
Pedals: Alloy body w/alloy cage
Saddle: Bontrager H2 Flex Form
Seatpost: Bontrager Nebula
Handlebar: Bontrager SSR OS, 25mm rise
Stem: Bontrager SSR, 10 degree
Headset: Aheadset Slimstak w/semi-cartridge bearings, sealed
Brakeset: Avid SD SD-3 w/Tektro adjustable reach levers

**2015 FX 7.2**

Frame: FX Alpha Silver Aluminium, DuoTrap S compatible, rack and mudguard mounts
Fork: High-tensile steel w/lowrider mounts, CLIX dropouts
Front hub: Formula TK31 alloy
Rear hub: Formula FM32 alloy
Rims: Bontrager AT-750 32-hole double-walled alloy 
Tyres: Bontrager H2 Hard-Case Lite w/puncture resistant belt, 700x35c
Shifters: Shimano Altus EF51, 8 speed
Front derailleur: Shimano M191
Rear derailleur: Shimano Acera M360
Crank: Shimano M131, 48/38/28 w/chainguard
Cassette: Shimano HG31 11-32, 8 speed
Pedals: Nylon body w/alloy cage
Chain: KMC Z7
Saddle: Bontrager SSR
Seatpost: Bontrager SSR, 27.2mm, 12mm offset
Handlebar: Bontrager Low Riser, 25.4mm, 15mm rise
Stem: Bontrager SSR, 25.4mm,10 degree
Headset: VP, semi-cartridge bearings, sealed
Brakeset: Tektro alloy linear-pull brakes, Shimano Altus levers
Grips: Bontrager Satellite

Comment: It's a little hard to find the specs for the old bikes, here's [a link](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/2015/archive/). I couldn't actually find out how to navigate there from the home page, but I was able to get there with a Google search.

Comment: I realize the 7.5 has better specs. What I don't know is how much of a difference the 5 years makes. E.g. are the 5 year old components obsolete? Does 5 years matter in terms of life left given the bike hasn't been ridden much? I can see specs on the trek site, but I'm having trouble finding info on those specs.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. I think if you edit your question to focus on the issue of how much bike technologies change over time, you'll get better responses. You'll also notice a lot of similar questions that may help you out on the right side of this page. There was even a very similar question asked recently (possibly even a [duplicate](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)), but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: See [this answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/20397/3927).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a bike hasn't been ridden but stored in a nice environment (e.g. a garage) for a few years and it was in good condition when it was put in, all you have to do is:

- Dust it off
- Pump up tires
- Lube the chain and other moving parts
- Check the brake pads are still good

Then ride away.

300 gentle miles on a bike is practically new. A bicycle sitting idle for 5 years is pretty much nothing. And bike parts are available through your LBS or online or ebay or spare parts bins for much longer than one may think. (I'd probably do a mechanical check on everything on the bike as well, but I suppose its not strictly necessary if the bike hasn't been touched in a long time)

I hesitate to answer this somewhat, since it somewhat verges on product recommendation, but the components on the 7.5 fx are better quality and compatible parts will be available for essentially the same amount of time as the 7.2 fx (pretty much all of them are cross compatible with whats on the 7.2 fx anyway, except the crankset + bb which is octalink vs jis, both extremely easy to get though). If the 7.5 fx is in excellent condition, it is the one I'd go for (possibly [talking down the price a bit](http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=19890&make=750&model=58263&year=2010)).

Answer (score 2):

At the level of bike you are looking at (2010 Trek 7.5 FX), most of the components will be easily found at your local bike shop or online. At this level, most manufacturers will use standard components which are easily obtainable, mostly because using any non-standard components would end up costing more, as they would only be produced in low quantities. Also, because they use standard components, and many other bikes use the same components, there is a big market for replacement parts, which means that finding replacement parts should be easy and inexpensive.  Assuming the used bike is in good condition, you shouldn't be worried about being able to find replacement parts when the time comes. As you move up to more exotic/expensive bikes, you'll start to see more unique parts that may be harder or more expensive to replace on older models.

Answer (score 1):

2010 Trek 7.5 FX has the better frame. Components can always be replaced or upgraded. Alpha Black Aluminum is directly comparable to Alpha Gold Aluminum. The 2015 Trek 7.2 has an Alpha Silver Aluminum frame. Not to mention, you get a carbon fork from the 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy a new Trek, you will get a lifetime warranty on the frame.  Warranties are not transferrable on a used Trek.  I have a Trek 7.2 fx, and it shifts very smoothly, and stops on a dime.  Only upgrades are a plush gel seat, and a water bottle cage.  My bike has a kickstand,  which does not add much weight, and the convenience that it provides makes it worth while. I can't find anything wrong with the 7.2 fx.  You never really know what you are getting with a used bike. You may need to change components on the used bike.  You don't know if it had been properly lubed throughout the last 5 years. All of that cost more money, which will put you over your budget.  If you buy a new bike, the dealer will set it up for you, and usually will give you a free tuneup after 30 days.  I would buy the new bike.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles - please remember we don't do product recommendations.  A year later this question is obsolete because time marches on.  Good point about non-transferable warranty.    Consider browsing the Tour in the Help menu to learn how Stack Exchange is a little different to other websites.